# Is it possible to trigger an Ajax CallBack Function After a Link is Click

Tags: forms, ajax

I have a simple link in my form.

```
$form['myid_print']['myid_print_search_idnumber_wrapper'] = array(
  '#type' => 'item',              
  '#markup' => '<a>Im a link....</a>',                                    
);
```

Is it possible to trigger an ajax callback function after a link is click? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah you just need to use `use-ajax` class for this.

```
$form['myid_print']['myid_print_search_idnumber_wrapper'] = array(
  '#type' => 'item',              
  '#markup' => l(t('Test Ajax'), 'admin/ajax-url/nojs', array('attributes' => array('class' => 'use-ajax'))),
);
```

Checkout this blog : http://www.computerminds.co.uk/drupal-code/make-link-use-ajax-drupal-7-its-easy.